# gcc tail call optimization with -O2 but not -O3

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization, tail-recursion

I've read in a few places that `gcc` tries to perform tail-call optimization when called with `-O2` but not with `-O3`. Why would the latter optimize less than the former? The former should perform less optimization.

Comment: "in a few places": care to point those out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's accurate. From the gcc documentation (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), the flag `-foptimize-sibling-calls` is responsible for tail recursion elimination, and is enabled at both -O2 and -O3.

```
-foptimize-sibling-calls
    Optimize sibling and tail recursive calls.

    Enabled at levels -O2, -O3, -Os.
```

Answer (score 0):

RTFM.

> -O3 turns on all optimizations specified by -O2

(https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options)